# How to assign columns names in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the filtered Pandas table (dataframe). Is it possible to assign manually using UI interface the columns names and move fields across dataframe by mouse?

Comment: What's the point of doing that?

Comment: There's no built-in tool for interactively editing pandas dataframes.

Comment: I need to resort values in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to change the order of columns in a table if that's your question

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c':['c1','c2','c3'],
    'a':['a1','a2','a3'],
    'b':['b1','b2','b3'],
})

print('Original column order')
print(df)
#Original column order
#    c   a   b
#0  c1  a1  b1
#1  c2  a2  b2
#2  c3  a3  b3


reordered_df = df[['a','b','c']]
print('Reorderd columns')
print(reordered_df)
#Reorderd columns
#    a   b   c
#0  a1  b1  c1
#1  a2  b2  c2
#2  a3  b3  c3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rename columns , you can do the following :

```
df.rename(columns={'col_a':'new_col_a'}, inplace=True)
```

For alignment you can simply follow @[mitoRibo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72495801/14306125) suggestion.